# Android Auto stopped working with Pixel 3 on Hyundai Elantra

Tags: android-auto

I have a 2018 Hyundai Elantra with Android Auto and a Pixel 3, and I use Android Auto often.  I recently upgraded my phone to Andriod 10 and after a few days Android Auto stopped working.  I have rebooted my phone and tried a new cable to no avail.  I had a friend connect an iPhone to my car and CarPlay worked normally, so I know it isn't a problem with the car's USB port.

Does anyone have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying to "restart" Android Auto in your car by disabling Android Auto, waiting a minute or two, then enabling Android Auto.  I believe you can turn off Android Auto from the touch screen under Setup, Phone Projection.

Give this a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks, Jim!